# jQuery validation with any inputs before an 'require_from_group_exact' validated input does not validate properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I am using the jQuery Validation Plugin to validate a number of inputs on a html page.  The first name is always required, and either email OR mobile but not both.  To do this, I use the require_from_group_exact method.

When the inputs are in this order, validation occurs perfectly:

```
<form>
  Email: <input class="commsinfo" name="email"><br>
  Mobile: <input class="commsinfo" name="mobile"><br>
  Name: <input name="firstname"><br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

However if you swap the inputs around, validation of the last input (firstname) does not occur properly (you have to type a firstname and then delete it to trigger validation) - **why??**.  This is the desired order and issue I'm trying to solve - is it a bug with the jQuery Validation Plugin or my code?

```
<form>
  Name: <input name="firstname"><br>
  Email: <input class="commsinfo" name="email"><br>
  Mobile: <input class="commsinfo" name="mobile"><br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

I have created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/14tbkp28/21/) of the version the does not validate properly.  The code for the jQuery.validator.addMethod and $('form').validate can be seen in the fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not checking all the input fields,

change `var fields = $(selector, element.form);`

to `var fields = $('form :input');`

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/14tbkp28/25/)

Comment: I think I misinterpreted what `valid()` does. I was under the impression that it just returned a value indicating the validity of the form and nothing else. I guess I was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

In the example you've provided, there seems to be an issue with the call to `fields.valid()`.

I've updated the fiddle to remove some code I don't think you need. The call to `valid()` seems to be the crux of the problem and removing it causes the validation to work as expected.

The updated code now looks like this:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("require_from_group_exact", function(value, element, options) {
  var validator = this;
  var selector = options[1];
  var validOrNot = $(selector, element.form).filter(function() {
    return validator.elementValue(this);
  }).length == options[0];

  return validOrNot;
}, jQuery.format("Please fill {0} of these fields."));

$('form').validate({
  rules: {
    firstname: { required: true },
    email: { require_from_group_exact: [1, ".commsinfo"] },
    mobile: { require_from_group_exact: [1, ".commsinfo"] },
  }
});
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yassarikhan786/14tbkp28/24/)

Comment: Doesn't work, try submitting an empty form and entering a value for email. The message for mobile does not dissapear.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I didn't realise. Your solution is the most appropriate.

Comment: Validation works as expected, although once an error message is shown it should be removed as you type with valid data.  For example, submitting a blank email and mobile gives an error.  As you begin to type an email, the mobile message remains when it should disappear.  I think that's a result of @TheOnlyError removing that section of the code.

Comment: Have you looked @TheOnlyError's example fiddle?

Comment: Roger - the perfect solution!  It can also includes validation of `<textarea>` inputs which is a huge bonus! TYVM.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you call the

```
fields.valid();
```

your validator method is recalled and so you get the apparently strange behaviour. You can check this debugging by yourself.